# Representing function as power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

How can I represent $f=\dfrac{2x+1}{x^2+x-6}$ as a power series?I can see that this is the derivate of $\ln(x^2+x-6)$ is it of any help here?

I'm new to this chapter and don't know how to start this problem

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions?

Comment: And after that represent it as a geometric series? Didn't think of that ,thank you.But what about the fact that it's a derivate of that log?Does it help in any way?

Comment: You can split the logarithm into two components by factorising the polynomial.

Comment: I tried breaking it into partial fractions but when I do that the result isn't the same with the one I find using the log.Could you please help me with the first approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using partial fractions:

$$f(x)=\frac 1{x+3}+\frac 1{x-2}=\frac 13\cdot\frac 1{1+\frac x3}-\frac 12\cdot\frac 1{1-\frac x2}$$

$$\frac 1{1+\frac x3}=1-\frac x3+\frac {x^2}9- \dots +(-1)^n\frac {x^n}{3^n}+\dots$$$$\frac 1{1-\frac x2}=1+\frac x2+\frac {x^2}4+ \dots +\frac {x^n}{2^n}+$$So the general term should be $$\left(\frac {(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}-\frac 1{2^{n+1}}\right)x^n$$

Comment: Thank you very much I got it now.Also what happens with the radius of convergence in this case?Because for the first sum I see it would be 3 and 2 for the 2nd.How do I find it for the whole term?

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(x^2+x-6)=\ln(x-2)(x+3)=\ln(x-2)+ln(x+3)=$$
$$=\ln(1+(x-3))+\ln(1+(x+2))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-3)^n}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x+2)^n}{n}$$
for finding series for $f(x)$ it will be derivative:
$$\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x-6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}(x-3)^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}(x+2)^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(x-3)^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(x+2)^{n}$$

Comment: shouldn't i derivate the expression and not integrate it?

Comment: yes. sure. now i'll fix it